# Incoherence between eloquent `isDirty()` and `getChanges()`

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I am currently working on a Laravel 5.8 project and when updating a model noticed that even though there aren't any changes to the model I'm saving the same model back into the database.

My thinking to avoid this was the following:

```
$model = Model::find($id);
$model->fill([
    "name" => $request->name,
    ...
]);
if($model->isDirty){
    $model->save()
}
```

Problem is that even though I don't change values in my model I'm still entering the `if()` condition and saving the model. I tried using a temp variable and debugged `$model->getChanges()` and I get an empty array.

Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 8):

There is a difference yes.

Related code:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L1060

isDirty code

```
/**
 * Determine if the model or any of the given attribute(s) have been modified.
 *
 * @param  array|string|null  $attributes
 * @return bool
 */
public function isDirty($attributes = null)
{
    return $this->hasChanges(
        $this->getDirty(), is_array($attributes) ? $attributes : func_get_args()
    );
}
```

getChanges() & getDirty code

```
/**
 * Get the attributes that have been changed since last sync.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getDirty()
{
    $dirty = [];
    foreach ($this->getAttributes() as $key => $value) {
        if (! $this->originalIsEquivalent($key, $value)) {
            $dirty[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $dirty;
}
/**
 * Get the attributes that were changed.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getChanges()
{
    return $this->changes;
}
```

To summarize.

Answer used from this post: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/observer-column-update-isdirty-or-waschanged

> isDirty (and getDirty) is used BEFORE save, to see what attributes
>   were changed between the time when it was retrieved from the database
>   and the time of the call, while wasChanged (and getChanges) is used
>   AFTER save, to see that attributes were changed/updated in the last
>   save (from code to the database).

The reason you get in the isDirty check is that before the check you do a fill(). I think this will auto-fill updated_at. So, in fact, the model, in this case, has been changed.